# Addition of custom-fields

Tags: custom-fields

I would like to know if it is possible to customize the description of the contacts or any objects of the system? 
Can we enrich dropdown lists? 
Can we add fields and indicate it's a text, a date, a decimal, a booelan etc...
Can we reorganise the tabs layout and mix standard fields and customized fields as we want?

Thank you for your answer 
Regards
Evelyne PLEE-LEMOYNE

Comment: Maybe someone can answer all your questions, but you're asking quite a few things together, whereas usually the posts here are targeting a specific problem. If you want an introduction to CiviCRM and its capabilities I'd suggest checking out the [User Guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your interest in CiviCRM. Broadly, the answer to your question is 'YES'.

Since CiviCRM is open source software it is possible to customise anything and everything. However, some things are much easier to customise than others.

For example you can easily make changes to the configuration to do the following:

- [customise the user interface](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/initial-set-up/customizing-the-user-interface/) - including dropdowns, display preferences and search preferences
- [create custom fields](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/)
- [create profiles](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/organising-your-data/profiles/) - to collect or display related fields

Other changes may require custom coding and so may require a developer to make the change for you (or you could learn how to do this yourself if you are that way inclined).

If you have specific questions about any of these topics it would be best to post them as separate questions. As [mickadoo says](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19321/addition-of-custom-fields#comment21722_19321) StackExchange works best if you just ask one question per 'question'.